# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'on'

Tags: bots, telegram, attributeerror, coroutine, telethon

Good afternoon, I'm experimenting with the telethon library and immediately came across an error. Why is this happening?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id=4563456
api_hash='5453gfgderfth5656uedgh56hdfg'
token_tg='234523452:ddfghe4356b345345g34364bn67'

bot = TelegramClient('botu2', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=token_tg)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def send_welcome(event):
    await event.reply('Howdy, how are you doing?')

@bot.on(events.NewMessage)
async def echo_all(event):
    await event.reply(event.text)

bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

Returns an error:

```
<module>
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'on'
```

What could be the problem, because the code was copied from the telethon documentation?

Answer (score 0):

you should split your start into two pieces:

```
bot = TelegramClient('botu2', api_id, api_hash)
bot.start()
```